# Many to many relationship is only partly resolved

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm having some trouble with EF 5 Code First, mainly because i don't know for what behaviour i have to look for.

It's about writing a calendar backend.

A Calendar includes a list of CalendarEntries
A Calendar is owned by a user
A CalendarEntry has an owner(same as it's calendar)
A CalendarEntry has an optional list of invites
A user has a list of all of his invites.

The problem is:
When i add users to a calendar entry it works, but when a want to add the same user to another entry the first calendar entry loses the user (CalendarEnty.Invitees)

On the other hand the amount of invites for a user is listed correctly and also the invite table has the correct values.

Any hint on how to solve this issue?

```
    public class Calendar
{
    [Key]
    public int CalendarId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CalendarEntry> CalendarEntries { get; set; }
    }

 public class CalendarEntry
{
    public CalendarEntry()
    {
        Invitees = new List<User>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Invitees { get; set; }


    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            if (Invitees.Count == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


    [Key]
    public int CalendarEntryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return EndDate.Subtract(StartDate).TotalMinutes;
        }
    }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    public int CalendarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}

   public class Invite
{

   [Key]
   public int InviteId { get; set; }
   public virtual CalendarEntry CalendarEntry { get; set; }
   public int Accepted { get; set; }
   public virtual User Owner {get; set;}

}

    public class User
{
    [Key]

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]       
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    [Required]    
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]       
    public string MailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Calendar Calendar { get; set; }
    public int? CalendarId { get; set; }

    //SHA512Hashed

    private string _password = null;
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            _password = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invite> Invites { get; set; }
}
```

The ids for user and invites are used to access the items easier from a WCF service
That's why i'm not using combined keys

With the following method i ensure that a user is only added one time, i suspect this will cause some trouble? Unfortunately i realldy don't know how to work around it.

```
        public int AddUser(User dbUser)
    {
        var users = this.GetAllUser();

        if (users != null && users.Where(p => p.MailAddress == dbUser.MailAddress).Count() > 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        try
        {
            _calendarDatabase.User.Add(dbUser);
            _calendarDatabase.SaveChanges();
            return dbUser.UserId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your User model, but I suspect that you haven't declared a reference to (a collection of) CalendarEntry models in it. Make sure you have declared it something like:

```
public class User
{
  public ICollection<CalendarEntry> CalendarEntries { get; set; }
  // ... other User properties
}
```

If you leave out this reference, then EF will assume the relationship between CalendarEntry and User is many-to-one, which means that any given User can only be associated with a single CalendarEntry (though each CalendarEntry may have multiple Users). So, when you assign a User to a CalendarEntry, it is removed from any previous relationship.

By putting in the navigation property (as a collection) in the `User` model, you tell EF that in fact this relationship is many-to-many, and in this case it will generate a mapping table for you behind the scenes to allow a User to be associated with any number of CalendarEntries.

**EDIT** -

When you have a many-to-many relationship in EF, you can either specify a mapping table for the relationship explicitly, or just let EF generate the table for you based on the navigation properties you define in your objects. By putting a collection property in each object that refers to the other, EF can infer the many-to-many relationship and act accordingly.

When you have additional information for the relationship, such as a bit indicating whether or not the `User` has accepted an `Invite` for a `CalendarEntry` as in your code, you need to specify the mapping table explicitly. When you do this, the easiest way to code it in EF is to have each of the parties to the relationship have a navigation property which is a reference to a collection of *the mapping object*, as opposed to the other object in the relationship.

So, in your case, this line in `CalendarEntry`:

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Invitees { get; set; }
```

should probably be:

```
public virtual ICollection<Invite> Invitations { get; set; }
```

To get the behavior you expect (e.g., letting a `User` be related to multiple CalendarEntry objects via the Invite mapping object).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! The user model is part of the post. Unfortunately you have to scroll inside the code block. I will try to fix that. Regarding your hint: i will definetely try that! thanks so much!

Comment: One thing that is not clear to me. From my perspective there is no many to many relationship between user and calendar. Because this should exist between CalendarEntry and user based on the invitation model. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry if I missed the rest of your code block. I see that you have an `Invite` class which serves as the mapping table for the many-to-many relationship between `User` and `CalendarEntry`. Because you are specifying an explicit mapping table, you don't need the `ICollection<User> Invitees` in your `CalendarEntry` object. You should instead have an `ICollection<Invite> Invitations` or something similar. When you want to find the users who have been invited to the `CalendarEntry`, you can navigate through the `Invite` object.